# Web Service , Web API , API What are All These?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I found so many answers but haven't got one suits my (basic) "Knowledge".

These are troubling for me, kindly guide me.

I know what **API** is (from the local concept  like  `GetCursorPos()` winApi of user32.dll)

**Q: what is WebApi?**

**Ans**   : web API is a API which is exposed via the web.

**Q:what is WebService?**

**Ans**   :  is a software function provided at a network address over the web.

**My Doubts:**
is a WebApi used to Achieve a Service through web? Access a WebService?

What Differs  WebService  and Web API?

The following makes me again weird:

> A Web services describes a standardized way of integrating Web-based applications using the XML, SOAP, WSDL and UDDI open standards over an Internet protocol backbone.
>
> A web API is a development in web services where emphasis has been moving to simpler representational state transfer (REST) based communications

Then What is this Web API for?

Also seen that WebServices = API + Http ( Api refers to Web Api?)

**What are Web Service API?**

Answer (score 1):

Web Services:
    *To achieve the **platform interoperability** Web Services are being used, and it is a **SOA** based. It follows standards like **WSDL,SOAP, UDDI** and so on. WSDL passed through SOAP protocol and will be accessed by clients, by having **stubs** generated out of WSDL.*

Web API:
    *Now a days a new paradigm of achieve the platform independent services are done by **RESTful web services or Web API**'s. It rely on HTTP protocol, and these services will be accessed by HTTP clients like browser or a HTTP client code. WebAPI is an another name to describe these both client and server API's.*

Hope it makes clear